# Incorrectly displayed names using scale_linetype_manual in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

Let's say that my data is the following

```
structure(list(Date_spill = structure(c(14821, 14821, 14821, 
14822, 14822, 14822, 14823, 14823, 14823, 14824, 14824, 14824, 
14825, 14825, 14825, 14826, 14826, 14826, 14827, 14827, 14827, 
14828, 14828, 14828, 14829, 14829, 14829, 14830, 14830, 14830
), class = "Date"), name = c("Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", 
"Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", 
"Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", 
"Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", 
"Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", 
"Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", 
"Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", 
"Total_Semi.V2", "Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2"
), value = c(49.4546983682789, 51.9303086440996, 92.629674668831, 
49.4548705378623, 51.9568197311001, 92.6639221895955, 49.4050580381077, 
52.0759311138546, 92.6960916166521, 49.4105943879168, 52.0780444332815, 
92.7383532168068, 49.4138062869719, 52.1659343814577, 92.7264996022303, 
49.9540234458416, 52.7289455840081, 92.8136667785365, 49.9103140374395, 
52.8808260158253, 92.805208075033, 49.655075046784, 51.7281324622375, 
92.7607146196158, 49.6062909588621, 51.8989768324288, 92.7160066233307, 
49.3349721254447, 51.6577369988633, 92.6983797038236)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have a plot with 3 lines and I define the color and type of this lines using `scale_linetype_manual` and `scale_color_manual`. The problem is that when I use both commands the line's names does not correspond to the correct model.

The code that i am using is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(Total, aes(x = Date_spill, y=value, colour = name, linetype = name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_test() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkseagreen3", "skyblue3", "firebrick3"), 
                     labels = c("MHAR-ReVar",
                                "MHAR-ReCov", 
                                "MSHAR")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:3, 
                        labels = c("MHAR-ReVar",
                                   "MHAR-ReCov", 
                                   "MSHAR")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(x = "", y="")
```

The result is the following, and the problem is that the legend does not coincide with the data. I want to say that the red dotted line represent the data of MHAR-ReVar, the solid line represent the MHAR-ReCov data
[image]

Comment: In your call to `scale_color_manual` you probably need to add a `breaks = ...` argument to match the order of the actual break values used with the proposed `labels` and `values`

Comment: ... the issue is that ggplot by default orders your variable `name` alphabetically and then assigns the provided colors, labels, linotypes, ... in that order, i.e. `Total_Cov.V2` comes first in the alphabet and therefore gets assigned the first label `"MHAR-ReVar"`.

Comment: @stefan great observation! I change the names in my original data and i got the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(Total, aes(x = Date_spill, y=value, colour = name, linetype = name)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme_test() +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2"),
                     values = c( "firebrick3", "darkseagreen3", "skyblue3"), 
                     labels = c("MHAR-ReVar",
                                "MHAR-ReCov", 
                                "MSHAR")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("Total_Var.V2", "Total_Cov.V2", "Total_Semi.V2"),
                        values = c(2, 1, 3), 
                        labels = c("MHAR-ReVar",
                                   "MHAR-ReCov", 
                                   "MSHAR")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1), 
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(x = "", y="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>